# Fck Editor upload images

Tags: c#, image, upload, fckeditor

I have a problem with images in FCK editor. when i try to upload images it gives me Connector disabled error and the images are not showing in the editor page. i am programming with visual studio 2008. please help

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the following code:

```
private bool CheckAuthentication()
    {
        // WARNING : DO NOT simply return "true". By doing so, you are allowing
        // "anyone" to upload and list the files in your server. You must implement
        // some kind of session validation here. Even something very simple as...
        //
        //        return ( Session[ "IsAuthorized" ] != null && (bool)Session[ "IsAuthorized" ] == true );
        //
        // ... where Session[ "IsAuthorized" ] is set to "true" as soon as the
        // user logs in your system.
        MembershipUser m = Membership.GetUser();
        if (m != null)
        {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        //return false;
    }
```

Then update both App and Root files.